# Was the song for the Thunderbirds end titles originally 'Flying High'?

Tags: thunderbirds

As can be seen in this clip (below) there is an alternative ending credits for the Thunderbirds series:

This was a fan-made clip as the poster explains in the comments below, but also indicates that the song 'Flying High' was going to be used for the end credits.  Is this true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Yes

Here is an excerpt from *[The Complete Book of Thunderbirds 40th Anniversary Edition](http://thunderbirds.wikia.com/wiki/The_Complete_Book_of_Thunderbirds)* about it:

> Early in August, Barry Gray recorded **'Flying High', a song performed
>   by Garry Miller for *Thunderbirds'* end title sequence**, but he was
>   unhappy with the session and re-recorded it twice in early September
>   [1965].  *'Flying High' was to have followed the tradition set by
>   *Fireball XL5* and *Stingray* where each episode ended with a song that would act as an alternative theme tune to the one used in the
>   series' opening titles*.  Gerry Anderson ultimately decided that having
>   a song (and, in particular, this song) playing over the end titles no
>   longer suited the format of the series, so **'Flying High' was scrapped
>   and replaced by the 'Thunderbirds March'** just a fornight before the
>   first episode was transmitted.

(Page 29)

So, as you can see, **yes** 'Flying High' *was* originally intended to be used as the theme song for the end of *Thunderbirds*, supported also by the fact that Anderson's past series' had also used this format of having a vocal song during the end credits.

As mentioned in the comment for that video in the question, that is the original song, however I cannot find any videos of the *original* end titles with this song in the background; only fan-made versions.  It is quite possible, considering the above quote, that these end-titles were never actually made with 'Flying High' in the background!